# Joomla 3.x - Good approach to save multiple select list data?

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla component for which I added a multiple select list and made some component core edits. I was surprised that I have to make such edits just to save multi select data. Shouldn't joomla core be able to do this?

Anyway, here is what I did, but I would like to know what you recommend as a better approach. I have heard that plugins might be the way to go but I have no experience with joomla plugins and am not sure how I would use them.

The xml is

```
<field
name="expertise"
type="list"
label="Area of Expertise"
required="true"
multiple="true"
/>
```

In the model, I added this to LoadFormData

```
if ( ! is_array($data->expertise))
    {
        $data->expertise= explode(',', $data->expertise);
    }
```

And in controller I added this

```
protected function postSaveHook(JModelLegacy &$model, $validData = array())
{

    if(isset($validData['expertise'])){
        if (is_array($validData['expertise'])) $data['expertise'] = implode(',', $validData['expertise']);
    }

    $model->save($data);
}
```

Thoughts on a better/more appropriate approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me.

I am just curious why you do not make your data checks in the same if structure like this:

```
if(isset($validData['expertise']) && is_array($validData['expertise']))
{
    $data['expertise'] = implode(',', $validData['expertise']);
}
```

That is easier to read IMO.

I think your approach is pretty similar to how it is done at http://www.component-creator.com. You can try and build a component with a multiple select field and see how code it generates compares.